# How to deal with errors in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am a former COBOL programmer (71 years old), trying to develop a personnal app in Flutter, stucking at an error while migrating PROVIDER to null safety. May you imagine the nightmare?

Is there a step by step way to deal with errors in Flutter?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of info on migration to null safety can be found [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide).

For step by step errors, you want to use the debugger found in the DevTools (or in VS Code/Android Studio). It will run the app and pause execution every time an error or a breakpoint is reached (DevTools debugger ignores errors by default, there's a dropdown button to change that).

DevTools also include a Provider vizualiser but I'm not sure if it will be helpful to you.